# Split full name into lastname,firstname if lastname has multiple parts (i.e. van, de)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list with multiple names, however, some names have multiple last names: Ex. "Eddie van Halen. I can't get my code to output: "van Halen, Eddie", instead it outputs: "Van, Eddie"

Would there be a way to check if names() has more than 2 parts, and if so to include names(1) & names(2) as last name instead of checking for "van". That is if a last name includes other parts such as "de".

Additionaly, if the full name does not have multiple parts, ex: "volunteer", the code should skip this name.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub Filter()

Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim names() As String
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet

Set r = .Range("K3:K" & lastrow)

For Each c In r
    names = Split(c.Value, " ")

    If IsEmpty(c.Value) Then Exit Sub

    ElseIf InStr(c.Value, "van") > 0 Then

        c.Value = names(1) & names(2) & ", " & names(0)

    Else
        c.Value = names(1) & ", " & names(0)

    End If
Next c

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know that the third name is not part of the first like `Mary Lou Smith`

Comment: I don't have any names with multiple first names but it would be optimal to include that condition as well if my list of names does include a "Mary Lou Smith" in the future.

Comment: Relevant: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @thevancanfan it is literally impossible to parse "Mary Lou Smith" without additional information. The last name could be "Lou Smith", or it could be a first / middle / last. Common prefixes "van", "von" "de" "d'", "van den", "vanden", "le", "la", "di", etc., can probably be handled with some reasonable degree of accuracy (but with a fair amount of complexity), but you cannot expect 100% from any of this sort of approach.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no nice way to say that `Lou` is part of the first or part of the second, programatically, so while a "nice to have" it's more like "impossible". You could though just loop the array `names` backwards printing each item with a space, except for the last last item `names(0)` which you print with comma and then a space... At least then you have like a 90% solution. The other 10% will be the hundreds of edge cases that are impossible to account for fully.

Comment: If you want to assume the middle is always part of the last then change: `ElseIf InStr(c.Value, "van") > 0 Then` to `ElseIf ubound(names) > 1 Then`

Comment: ElseIf UBound(names) > 1 Then works for the multiple last name case. Thank you very much.

Comment: If I would be you I would make sure you have a column of first names, and a column of last names in the future instead of an 'option' to include a condition to maybe tell what is a first name or a last name.

Answer (score 2):

Split takes a third argument, "Limit", which can be used to stop splitting once the result will have that many entries.

```
    names = Split(c.Value, " ", 2)
```

In this case `names` will always have at most 2 elements.

Comment: I think this is the best solution with minimum effort. It won't solve for any complicated edge case, but does solve the specific problem that OP mentioned.

Comment: Would I be able to set that names must equal at least 2 parts? Ex. if my full name only includes one word I want to delete this cell. Could I do if "Ubound(names) < 1 Then c.Value.Delete"

Comment: @thevancanfan `If UBound(names) < 1 Then c.Value = vbNullString`

Comment: Thank you very much! If I wanted to shift up before the next index how would I implement "Shift:=xlShiftUp'? or Would I use offset?

Comment: @thevancanfan new questions get new posts.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you could use regular expression. The following regular expression matches all words which do not begin with *van*, *von*, *de* etc. You can add your words at will. As an edge case, the name itself can start with *van* or *von* (for instance, Vonder). In order to handle this case, I have added `\b` into match of the exclusion, so these prefixes must be stand-alone. The other case, as @ScottCraner noted, is three parts names (like `Mary Lou Smith` in his example). In this case you can maneuver these cases with `Count` of matches (`x` variable). For instance, you can concatenate any parts, if there are three names.

```
Sub F()

    '// Tools -> References -> Microsoft VBSscript Regular Expressions 5.5
    Dim re As RegExp, mc As MatchCollection, m As Match, s$, x%

    Set re = New RegExp
    re.IgnoreCase = True
    re.Global = True
    re.Pattern = "\b(?!(van|von|de)\b)[a-z]+"
    Set mc = re.Execute("van Halen, Vanzen")
    If mc.Count > 0 Then
        For x = 0 To mc.Count - 1
            MsgBox mc(x)
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No matches were found.", vbExclamation
    End If

    '// Output:
    '//   Halen
    '//   Vanzen

End Sub
```